# RSA-Algorithm Invalid Keys

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, key, rsa

im trying to implent a **rsa**-algo for learning purposes in **c#**

The problems which i have are that some of my randomly created Keys are not working.

**Some Details:**

- im already using a BigInteger type to prevent overflowexception etc.
- i checked for mathematical dependencies(*p and n as Prims, e < !(N) and relative Prime and e > 1*)
- extended Euclid Algo is working properly, i counter checked it with some Online-Calculators(http://johannes-bauer.com/compsci/eea/index.php?zahl1=469&zahl2=2280&step=9999&detailliert=1&stepbystep=1)
- my encryption and decryption procedures are working fine i quess, cause they spill out 
  sometimes right values. So the key which is used must be wrong?!

**I captured some of the Keys which are not working:**

```
Prime numbers: p = 743 q = 37
Public key: e = 6371 N = 27491
Private Key: d = 524 >(N) = 26712

Prime numbers: p = 859 q = 47
Public key: e = 2239 N = 40373
Private Key: d = 647 >(N) = 39468

Prime numbers: p = 823 q = 29
Public key: e = 9173 N = 23867
Private Key: d = 1538 >(N) = 23016

Prime numbers: p = 719 q = 31
Public key: e = 1759 N = 22289
Private Key: d = 851 >(N) = 21540

Prime numbers: p = 149 q = 47
Public key: e = 1317 N = 7003
Private Key: d = 502 >(N) = 6808

Prime numbers: p = 859 q = 37
Public key: e = 9859 N = 31783
Private Key: d = 2790 >(N) = 30888
```

Is there a dependency i missed?
Or could it be a something inside my Code or perhaps inside C#?

### Update:

**This is the Code for the extended Euclid its not mine**(http://amir-shenodua.blogspot.de/2012/06/extended-gcd-algorithm-extended.html)

**This are my Functions to calculate the Prims**(http://pastebin.com/79Pvsxe8)
I restricted the random to 100 for the Test-Case and i know that using the C# Random Class is a kind of Security Threat.

**These are my RSA-Functions**(http://pastebin.com/2GxS9EDK)

Comment: Without the actual code, the most we can tell you is, "there's probably something wrong with your code".

Comment: I'm not going to read your code, but I do have an RSA key generator at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/11/16/rsa-cryptography/) that you are welcome to look at. Certainly you should not perform the exponentiation then take the modulus, because the intermediate result will be huge. You should also hide p and q inside the key generator so that no one, not even you, know what they are.

Comment: Your `create_multiInversed` or extended euclid implementation is probably wrong. `e*d mod phi(n) != 1` for your first example

Comment: thanks you are a genius that was exactly the problem

Comment: [Meta discussion about this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222217/turn-comment-into-community-wiki-answer-or-downvote-question-for-community-delet). Cc @CodesInChaos.